# Installing Eclipse with installer behind proxy

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I downloaded latest Eclipse Mars package (June 2015). Now it's distributed with an installer. But the installer doesn't work because I'm behind proxy. How should I configure proxy settings for the installer?

Error I got:

> org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
>   download.eclipse.org:80 timed out

Comment: You can find eclipse package as archive in the download page, you just have to scroll down a little

Comment: @flafoux ah, thanks!